# ImportError: No module named bs4 Atom

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, atom-editor, importerror

I'm using Atom (1.53.0) for web scraping using Beautiful Soup.

I get an error message in the line:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
```

which reads:

```
ImportError: No module named bs4
```

When executing the following command in the terminal:

```
pip install beautifulsoup4
```

I get the result:

```
Requirement already satisfied: beautifulsoup4 in ./opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages (4.8.2)
Requirement already satisfied: soupsieve>=1.2 in ./opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from beautifulsoup4) (1.9.5)
```

***I noticed that the issue can be resolved when I close atom and reopen it.*** However, it is extremely inconvenient to close atom all the time. Is there a way to resolve this issue?

Some info)

Python version: 3.7.6

MacOs version: 10.15.5

Atom version: 1.53.0

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is the virtual environment activated when you face this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Error is that `bs4` module not found so try installing `bs4` instead of `beautifulsoup4`

```
pip install bs4
```